# which is efficient among the three methods and why there are three different methods to do the same and which to use where?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found by investigation that there are 3 methods to get a custom tag or directive in angular

1) give the file directly as file's location in templateUrl

```
/* controller */
var foundation = angular.module('foundation', []);
foundation.directive('viewdesign', function() {
 return {
   restrict : 'EA',
   templateUrl: "templates/viewdesign.html"
 };
});
```

2) give the stringified form in template

```
/* controller*/
var foundation = angular.module('foundation', []);
foundation.directive('viewdesign', function() {
 return {
   restrict : 'EA',
   template: <stringified template file contents>
 };
});
```

3) store the stringified form in templatecache and feed it

```
/* controller */
var foundation = angular.module('foundation', ["templates/viewdesign.html"]);

angular.module("templates/viewdesign.html", []).run(["$templateCache" ,
                                                     function( $templateCache)
       { $templateCache.put("templates/viewdesign.html",
                                     <stringified template file contents>
);
}]);
foundation.directive('viewdesign', function() {
 return {
   restrict : 'EA',
   templateUrl: "templates/viewdesign.html"
 };
});
```

so we can access the template in html as follows

```
<div ng-app="foundation">
    <viewdesign></viewdesign>
</div>
```

my doubts are

1. which is efficient among the three methods
2. why there are three different methods to do the same and
3. which to use where for better performance

Comment: Cook up some tests and see for yourself: http://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 1):

The first one will download the template using an AJAX request the first time the directive is used. It allows easily customizing the template by editing an HTML file.

The second one avoids that additional AJAX request by storing the template directly inside the directive. This forces you to modify the directive itself to customize the template.

The third one combines the two above techniques: it gets the template from a URL, but fills the cache immediately so that the AJAX request is unnecessary. That is useful because you can easily provide two versions of your JS file: one containing the directive without the template (letting the user customize the template as it wants to), and one containing the directive and a pre-filled cache containing its template (if the user is happy with the standard template).

Answer (score 0):

The first and the second method are same the only difference is that the first method is using external template and the second is using inline template. For better code organisation its better to use external template but this it is making an extra ajax call to the server

External template

```
var foundation = angular.module('foundation', []);
foundation.directive('viewdesign', function() {
 return {
   restrict : 'EA',
   templateUrl: "templates/viewdesign.html"
 };
});
```

viewdesign.html

```
<h1>Hi to you</h1>
```

Inline template

```
var foundation = angular.module('foundation', []);
foundation.directive('viewdesign', function() {
 return {
   restrict : 'EA',
   template: '<h1>Hi to you</h1>'
 };
});
```

The third tehnique preloads the template into your cache befor first time using it

```
$templateCache.put("templates/viewdesign.html",'<h1>Hi to you</h1>');
```